# Xcode Autolayout Constraints Confusion

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, interface-builder

I have a landscape based view that has a SKView (`skView`) inside of it. I want the width of `skView` to always be 100% of the view and a static height of 288. I have added some constraints but when I start the application in the simulator it ways gives me the same CGSize (568 x 288), regardless of if I pick iPhone 4 or 3.5.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGSize size = self.skView.bounds.size; // 568 x 288
    ...
}
```

What am I missing here?

### I've set up a sample project to illustrate the issue at hand

https://github.com/kyledecot/autolayout

[image]

**Update #1**

One user suggested that I see what the value of `self.skView.bounds.size` is in `viewWillAppear:` which yielded some strange results (I'm not really sure if they're helpful)

[image]

**Update #2**

After removing all constraints and re-adding them as one commenter (updated in the github sample project I posted) suggested I now have the following (still broken though):

[image]

The lines in IB are blue which I means there is no ambiguity but it still doesn't seem to be working.

**Update #3**

After receiving new constraints from user `matt` and using `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` the problem still seems to be prevalent. It seems that `skView`'s width never gets conformed to that of `view`

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot the text is cut off because on a 3.5 inch iPhone `skView` still has the width of 568 (iPhone 4 inch's width in landscape).

Comment: I think the view actually resizes in `viewWillAppear`, so check there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not resizing per-say, but rather expecting that `self.skView.bounds.size` to have the correct initial values in it (isn't that the whole point of autolayout?). Also, I don't implement viewWillAppear. All of my setup is done in `ViewDidLoad`.

Comment: @AMayes just for curiosity sake I implemented this method and output what the size was. I posted what the values were but I don't think it was very helpful output.

Comment: Is your initial view placed inside a Navigation Controller?  If not, landscape resizing will present some issues.  Also, you should pin the height.

Comment: @AMayes No, I didn't feel I needed one as this is a spritekit game w/ a single view/scene. Why would this only cause issues in landscape?

Comment: What are the constraints for skView in the Attributes Inspector (can you post a screen shot)? I would expect: `1)` the leading edge to be attached to the Superview `2)` the trailing edge to be attached to the SuperView `3)` a height = 288 constraint `4)` one more constraint to position the view vertically. As an aside, I never download random code from the Internet to compile on my Mac.

Comment: I believe I had something close to this but I went ahead and removed all constraints and re-added them as you suggested. I know you don't compile code off the internet but here is the git diff after adding the constraints (still not working though) - https://github.com/kyledecot/autolayout/commit/0e6b83876ff7dbdf6a1d99f7b32759da278cc8bd

Comment: Also, I added another screenshot of the constraints.

Comment: I fixed it and created a pull request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like the constraints of the view haven't been resolved yet when your view configuration code kicks in. That is, the frames at that time do not correspond the "real" layout that you have created using auto layout constraints (which should fit the `skView` to the `view`).

I have moved the code from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead and it turns out that, at this time of the layout process, the bounds of your `view` and `skView` have been updated and it seems to work for both 3.5" and 4" screens.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGSize skViewSize = self.skView.bounds.size;
    SKScene *scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skViewSize];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    [self.skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

[This tutorial](http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions) might shed some more light on the topic.

Btw, I have submitted a pull request with my changes to your sample repository so you can browse the change.

Answer (score 2):

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` are called before the constraints are handled in view controller.
If your views rely on the size only when the view is created (e.g. presentScene in your code) then you are better do it in `viewDidAppear` or in 'viewDidLayoutSubviews'.
I have tried your code in each of these methods (after commenting out the `viewWillAppear`) and it works as expected.

**EDIT**
I have changed the `scaleMode` in `wiewWillAppear` from `SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill` to `SKSceneScaleModeFill` and it works good as well.
I think that this is better approach than presenting the scene only after the view controller is presented.

Comment: vewDidLayoutSubviews is the better place to make some adjustments  because it is called before the view becomes visible so the user doesn't see the before and after the adjustments.  Whereas viewDidAppear is called after the view is visible so unless you play some other tricks the user sees the view changing shapes if you make any adjustments there.

Comment: @JoeC, I haven't said that something should be changed in the viewDidAppear. The question was why the view width is always 568 - even in iPhone 4. I have noticed that the width was checked in viewDidLoad method and suggested to try checking it in viewDidAppear or in viewDidLayoutSubviews because these are called after the auto layout is applied.

Answer (score 2):

i think there is one short cut method..
first of all u have to checkmark on "Use Auto Layout" from the File Inspector,
Then there is four button is showed in interface builder , 1:align 2:Pin 3:Reslove autolayout Issues and 4:resizing behaviour..
now select any object, you want to show same in landscape and portrait mode,
and then click on third button(Reslove autolayout) .. select "add missing constrain in view controller" or "add missing constrain in view" as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

First, your original constraints were completely wrong; you do not want a vertical space from the top and bottom of the SKView if you also want the vertical height to be fixed! Those two things are opposites of each other.

Second, there's a bug in Xcode. :( You can see it in your second set of constraints. The top constraint to the Top Layout Guide has come out wrong (you can see that from the -288). You have accidentally formed a constraint from the Top Layout Guide to the *bottom* of the SKView (that's the Xcode bug, it does that to you). Here's how to work around the bug:

- Delete the top constraint.
- Move the SKView down the screen.
- Control-drag to form the top constraint to the Top Layout Guide again.
- Now select the top constraint and manually set its Constant to 0, to make the SKView move back up again.

The result will be:

- SKView has a height constraint of 280.
- View (the main view) has a leading and following horizontal space constraint of 0 to the SKView, and a top constraint of 0 (not -288!) from the Top Layout Guide to the SKView.

Bingo, now everything will work correctly.

Comment: This appears to fix the problem but I fear that's due to a bad example on my part. In `viewDidLoad` if you debug what the size of `skView` is the width is always 568 (which is correct for iPhone 4 inch but not iPhone 3.5 inch). It appears the the `skView` is being chopped off on the sides but w/ the simple "Hello World" label example the bug/effect isn't noticeable.

Comment: You cannot learn anything in `viewDidLoad`. Nothing has its real dimensions then. It is way too soon. It is irrelevant here.

Comment: What would the first first spot in which the dimensions would be correct? `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: even when using viewWillAppear to load my scene (following how Apple does in their Adventure demo project) the sides appear to get cut off. I have included a screenshot in the update question as well as pushed that code up to the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't known the correct reason but put call `layoutIfNeeded` method and after it will show the currect size.

```
[self.skView layoutIfNeeded];
CGSize size = self.skView.bounds.size;
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems after calling layoutIfNeeded the size of the bounds is update but then I get 320x488. It seems to back backwards or something. It shouldn't be touching the height at all. Perhaps this gives someone an idea to the underlying problem. Also, I really don't like calling layoutIfNeeded as this kind of takes the "auto" part out of "autolayout".

Comment: I've added a sample project to Github that demonstrates the issue. I put the URL in the updated question if you'd care to take a look

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Michael Kessler's answer I've done some experiments.

In `viewDidAppear` I logged the sizes of the main view, skView and the scene.
For different scaleModes here are the results.

*SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill*

viewSize = {480, 320}, 
skViewSize = {480, 280}, 
sceneSize = {568, 280}

*SKSceneScaleModeFill*

viewSize = {480, 320}, 
skViewSize = {480, 280}, 
sceneSize = {568, 280}

*SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill*

viewSize = {480, 320}, 
skViewSize = {480, 280}, 
sceneSize = {480, 280}

So clearly the mode you want is **SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill** to make the scene size match exactly the view size.

You will note however that Hello, World is still off the right side of the screen.
The reason is that the position of the SKLabel is set when the SKScene is initialised which is in `viewDidAppear` when the scene size is the incorrect width.

You can reposition it as follows in your MyScene class. When the SKScene is resized this method is called.

```
-(void)didChangeSize:(CGSize)oldSize {
    _myLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width, self.size.height/2.0);
}
```

NOTE: Things appear to work with *SKSceneScaleModeFill* but what you have there is a scene of width 568, scaled to fit in 480 rather than a scene of width 480.